# Trying to return value from all method inside controller in a web api in one go

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, webapi

I am new to web api ,I have an web api Fg_StockController containing
1.Get method

```scharp
[HttpGet]
public Fg_data GET()
{
    Fg_data fg = new Fg_data();
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("SELECT A.TMR_FROM_GRD FROM REM_MST A WHERE A.TMR_PARAM_CD = 'FG_DESP_TAR'", conn);
        command.Connection = conn;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;                
        fg.TMR_FROM_GRD = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        return fg;
    }
}
```

Currently I am calling http://localhost:51232/Api/Fg_stock
It will return {"TMR_FROM_GRD":"8"}
Now I have extra method inside Fg_StockController as given Fg_ACT_GET,Fg_Displn_GET
And I want all the method inside controller called in one go

```csharp
public string Fg_ACT_GET()
{ 
    // Fetching value from db
    return TXT_FG_ACT.ToString();
}

// Despatch Plan
[HttpGet]
public Tuple<int, int> Fg_Displn_GET()
{
    // Fetching value from db
    return new Tuple<int, int>(numb, tonnage);
}
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: You should call other methods from `GET` method.

Comment: You would need to call the additional methods from one of the existing methods.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya you  mean Fg_ACT_GET & Fg_Displn_GET method inside GET method .

Comment: Yes... correct... that's what you need to do @Mohan

Comment: @jdweng i have tried to call all method inside a new  method public string AllMethod(){....All methods called here}.but getting  error ,what would be correct syntax any ref if you can provide

Comment: Need more info.

Comment: @jdweng In  [HttpGet]  public string  AllMethod(){ GET(); Fg_ACT_GET(); Fg_Displn_GET();}  i am calling as shown .but getting error "all code paths  return a value.is my syntax is correct for calling

Comment: I think that you are wrong on so many levels. When I do MVC for an api, I have in the controller just what the user of the api call sees, it is just a call to the service that produces the desired response. Then, I have the service, where I collect the data that I want to pass, in your case, the connection to the database should be on the service not on the controller

Comment: Why do you have a string being returned?  Should it be a void?

Comment: @jdweng i tried with void but while cheking it for single method GET e,g  public Void AllMethod(){ GET();) results fine but while adding other two method Fg_ACT_GET(); Fg_Displn_GET()  it reults error ""ExceptionMessage":"Multiple actions were found that match the request:"

Answer (score 0):

you can use below attribute for methods

```
 [Route("name of method")]
```

for example if you have several methods in on the controller you can write like this:

```
        [Route("test1")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
           
            return View();
        }
        [Route("test2")]
        public IActionResult Index2()
        {
           
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: @shayam i want all methods value to be returned or get in one go.

Comment: @Mohan could you please descrip more?